# How do I obfuscate data in variables in jinja2? e.g. variable = "John Smith", I want something like "Odsv Wgtvs"

Tags: python, django, jinja2

So I am trying to create a page where details are only shown to users who are logged in. I am able to change the content statically using

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

So I can replace something like `{{ celebrity.name` }} with `Dummy Name`, but then every occurrence of this is the same.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to mess with `celebrity.name` to obfuscate the actual data.

If there is no easy way I'll happily write my own function, but at this point I'm not sure if I should be writing it in jinja2 in the html template or if I should do it in views.py so would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def obfuscate(value, user):
    if user.is_authenticated():
        return value

    # do something before returning
    return '#SECRET#' + value + '#SECRET#'
```

This could be user in the template:

```
{{ celebrity.name|obfuscate:user }}
```

---

If the obfuscation has to be deterministic (same values always yield the same obfuscated result) you could use a hash function (will return giberrish, not real names), or a fixed dictionary which you use to subsitute names, or something else.

If the replacement can be non-deterministic, you could use some random char replacements.

Comment: This worked - thanks! I had trouble passing the `user.is_authenticated` part in the custom template filter so I just left that in the html template file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set`

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% set celebrity_name = celebrity.name %}
{% else %}
  {% set celebrity_name = "dummy" %}
```

Or do you want to have unique dummy values..? You could assign anything from Python to `celebrity_name` if you want to use different values.